# Electrical Circuit: Problem solving/Reading

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

We had this question today in a test at work, by the time we finished it not even the instructors we're entirely sure how to read this one.

The translation is Find out the V1 and V2, P1 and P2 (watts) of the resistors and Pg1 and Pg2 (watts) of the generators/energy sources, knowing the following:

Resistor1 = 2 Ω

Resistor2 = 3 Ω

Vg1 = 15V

Vg2 = 10V

Anyone can offer some insight on how do you read this, or rules to apply? I also made a hopefully correct simulation [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjA7CAMB00IQVhAZgrMkBMAWaAHGEqgGzpRkgq6rUCmAtFgFABO4EpIB0I%20fXjBDZ2nbqiTZ%20CNFOGoWANxl9J0gTz7aZ4HdthJl4udMjchO-OBT7DLAPbDSuYfgCc76uFjc%200tRZUAmEAMTBhCLBoCOYQACV6AGcASySAFwBDADsAY3oWIA)

Are those outputs right by any means?

The test is over btw ahahaha but out of sheer curiosity, everyone was kind of scratching their heads.

Comment: It is a simple series circuit. What kind of problem do you have here?

Comment: Please show us your work and explain your thought process. We don't hand out homework solutions here, even if you say that the test is over.

Answer (score 3):

Using Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL).
The two power supply oppose each other. So you could imagine that they "cancel" each other out. (Not exactly what is going on, but helps understanding). This imply there is a total of 5 volt flowing in the circuit.

Now that we know this we can easily also see that the total resistance of the circuit is 5 ohms. \$V=IR\$ solving for the current we get \$I=1A\$.

"The direction of an electric current is by convention the direction in which a positive charge would move". Saying so would mean the larger source voltage will dictate the current flow direction. 15V is large than 10V so we can picture the current moving in a clockwise direction. In this particular case.

This would imply you are measuring V1 in the opposite direction to current flow. Hence a negative voltage. "Not actually negative" Although you are measuring the current in V2 in the same direction as current flow. Meaning a positive voltage.

\$Power= I*V\$ , or \$Power = I^2 * R\$
Probably better to use current squared, this avoids negative power. As you are trying to calculate power dissipation I would assume. Useful for calculating P1 and P2.

You mentioned calculating finding Pg1 and Pg2 for these I would use \$Power= I* V\$ as you never mention source resistances. (Which also technically means the total resistance in this circuit is not 5 Ohms, which ruins the idea of using an ideal source). Anyway, Now the current direction matters again. I hope you can multiply by 1 and -1.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer, yes everything makes more sense right now and yes it was asking for dissipated power, and two generators with no specified resistance, so yeah it was just a hypothetical. Seems everyone lost sight of the KVL rule that they cancel themselves out.

Comment: I should mention @TarnaBar that I wrote P=I*V which is technically incorrect. It is more proper to use "E" to indicate the electromotive force. ( P= E * I ) Although I felt it was easier to understand if I used "V" instead. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is a series connection of two voltage sources and two resistors. You can reorder the elements in a series connection arbitrarily without affecting the circuit's overall operation (and, especially, the current flowing through it).

First off we can merge the two voltage sources to simplify the circuit. The two voltage sources are in series, but one of them is the opposite way around. Therefore we have to subtract them, giving us a new value of 5V for Vg1 while Vg2 disappears (and is replaced by a short).

Next we can lump the two resistors together, giving us 5 Ohms in total.

5V across 5 Ohms conveniently gives exactly 1A of current flowing through the circuit. This current flows through all of its elements because they are in series.

Finally, we can compute the voltages: V1's direction is opposite to the flow of current through R1. 1A through 2 Ohms is 2V. This means V1 is -2V. V2 goes in the same direction as the current, so it's 3V.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer, yes we mostly missed that the sources cancel themselves out, now it makes way more sense.